# Can we arrange $\{1,...,9\}$ in $3\times 3$ grid so the set of products of rows equals the set of products of columns?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, permutations, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

I find a interesting question of Prmo mock and Promys 2020

For which $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is it possible to arrange $\{1,…,n^2\}$ in an $n\times n$ grid so that the set of products of columns equals the set of products of rows?

I can find solution for $3\times 3$ or $4\times 4$ but unable to generalize for  $n\times n$.

The question has been answered by RobPratt but I am not understanding his solution its too hard for me nor I can ask the doubt to him due to lower reputation

Can anyone please help me in this question.

Comment: 1) Please give the reference of the answer gy Rob Pratt. 2) What is "Prmo mock and Promys 2020" ? A book ?

Comment: There are only $9! = 362 880$ possible permutations, so this can easily be brute-forced by computer.

Comment: @JeanMarie ma'am Prmo is math Olympiad , i am solving its mock qestions from prmo mock book . Promys 2020 means this question was asked in 2020 promys , this was mentioned in my mock book as a source

Comment: @MichaelLugoMy i am not understanding his solution ,,, that's why i asked  the question again sir

Comment: Rob Pratt answer can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518460/can-we-arrange-1-16-in-4-times-4-grid-so-products-of-rows-produ

Comment: @RobPratt i dont understand last part of your solution ""Let binary decision variable xi,j,k
 indicate whether cell (i,j)
 has value k
. You can use any objective function, and the constraints are:
∑kxi,j,k=1 ,,,,,,∑i,jxi,j,k=1,,,,,,,,,,∑j,klog(k)xt,j,k=∑i,klog(k)xi,t,k"" like what u did here , can u explain it please

Comment: There are less than $9!$ permutations. We must assume that $5$ and $7$ are in different rows and different columns (why)?, and by permutation of rows and columns we can put $5$ at $(1,1)$ and $7$ at $(2,2)$. Thus only $7!=5040$ trials, but with a little ingenuity I hit on my first try!