# Can we arrange numbers $\{1,...,25\}$ in a $5\times5$ matrix, so that the product of the $n$-th row equals the product of the $n$-th column.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Precisely, is it possible to construct a $5\times 5$ matrix $A$, where each entry is a distinct element of $\{1,\dots, 25\}$, so that
$$\prod_{i=1}^5 a_{ij}=\prod_{i=1}^5a_{ji}$$
for all $j\in\{1,\dots,5\}$. I know that one thing you can do is to arrange all the big primes on the diagonals first, but I am unsure of what to do next in order to complete a $5x5 grid$ that satisfies the condition.

Comment: When you say "Product of rows", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Like you place 5 numbers into a row, and you find the product of them..

Comment: Do you mean that the product of all numbers the $n$-th row is equal to the product of all numbers in the $n$-th column, or do you mean that the product of all numbers in each row and column is equal to the same constant?

Comment: For the 5x5 grid, the product of all numbers in the n-th row has to equal to the product of all numbers in the n-th columns. that is what I mean

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: you are wrong about $11$ because $22$ is also in the list.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518460/can-we-arrange-1-16-in-4-times-4-grid-so-products-of-rows-produ/3518847#3518847 !

Comment: @Dominique Oh right, thanks, this makes the question more interesting.